# ReactiveCocoa object not released when referenced in flattenMap

Tags: reactive-cocoa

When I reference a variable in flattenMap block, it is not getting released. See the code snippet -

```
TestMem * t = [[TestMem alloc] init];
[[[RACSignal return:nil]
  flattenMap:^RACStream *(id x) {
     return [t testFunc];
  }] subscribeNext:^(id x) {  
  } completed:^{
      NSLog(@"completed");
  }];
```

Implementation of TestMem is as follows:

```
@implementation TestMem

   - (void)dealloc {
       NSLog( @"dealloc is called: self=%@", self);
   }

   - (RACSignal *) testFunc {
      return [RACSignal return:nil];
   }

   @end
```

There is no circular reference with TestMem object and flattenMap block, so I assumed TestMem object - t, should get released, but it doesn't. If I use @Weakfy(t) & @strongify(t), the object is getting released. 
Can anyone explain why this is the case.

Comment: Check out the list at the very end of this document: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/MemoryManagement.md. Are you testing that the `dealloc` occurs before the current iteration of the run loop completes?

Comment: TestMem doesn't get deallocated, after the signal completes and the calling function returns. I am not sure, I understand how dealloc should happen, when the run loop complete. How do I know run loop is completed and when should dealloc actually happen?

Comment: I've just run your code code and get dealloc message after completed: `dealloc is called: self=<TestMem: 0x17001bdf0>`. Are you sure you are not missing something important? Where do you run this code? Is that iOS/Mac App, or, probably a command line app?

Comment: Thanks Ian for pointing me to the document. The memory did get released after the iteration of the run loop.